# LOAD Runner Internal server 500 issue (REST API)

Tags: rest, loadrunner, vugen

I am trying to run REST API from Load Runner but unable to do it. Every times its throws below exception

```
Action.c(4): Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "http://ipaddress/LoyaltyApi/api1/loyaltycard/linkcard", Snapshot Info [MSH 1 1]    [MsgId: MERR-26612]
```

My code :

```
Action()
{
    lr_think_time(10);
    web_custom_request("LinkCards",
                      "URL=http://ipaddress/LoyaltyApi/api1/loyaltycard/linkcard",
                      "Method=POST",
                      "Resource=0",
                      "EncType=application/json",
                      "Mode=HTTP",
                     "BodyFilePath=linkcards.json",
                      LAST);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested the same URL with POST parameter in `POSTMAN` and it's working fine without any issue.

I am very new in this technology so unable to solved the issue. Please help.

Comment: Error 500 generally means that this call is breaking server logic. Possibly something is missing (cookies, post parameters etc.) Is it recorded or manually written?

Comment: It is manually written dear actually we will not use recording for rest api because if i paste in browser it is giving glassfish message.so i did manually.

Comment: Could you add the configuration you used in `POSTMAN` to your question? It might help understanding what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

> I am very new in this technology....

Assuming your management has moved you to this role, have they provided you with training on the tool and a mentor for a period of time.  If not they have set you up for failure.

Comment: If you know the answer just provide here in case don't know the answer just ignore dear why this type of management is not provided training not good.

Comment: Because your issue is directly related to a validation of your foundation skills before beginning this profession, training on the tool and the availability of a mentor during your first several gigs, up to a year.   Or, if you must, this is directly related to poor testing skills, not checking for expected results (how is a tool mechanical skill), not branching your code when expected results fail (a tool language foundation skill) and potentially not handing dynamic data (a conceptual and tool mechanical skill)